# How to solve this jQuery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 divs above each others, at a given moment one is shown and the other is hidden, the script should display #div2 when the mouse enters #div1 and should show #div1 when the mouse leaves #div2

the problem comes when the mouse enters #div1 and leaves before #div2 is displayed so the #div2 will stay displayed but the mouse has left #div2 already
any help ?

My jQuery code:

```
$('#div1').mouseenter(function(){
 $('#div1').fadeOut("fast",function(){
  $('#div2').fadeIn("fast");
 });
});

$('#div2').mouseleave(function(){
 $('#div2').fadeOut("fast",function(){
  $('#div1').fadeIn("fast");
 });
});
```

Comment: tried to set animation speed faster?

Comment: tried but it doesn't seems to be a good solution, i made it 100 although sometimes the same problems happens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) here:

```
$("#div1, #div2").hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().fadeOut("fast");
}, function() {
  $(this).stop().fadeIn("fast");
});
```

**Note:** I've used [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) on the animations, which is a good habit to get into. The above version also allows both divs to have the same handler, which reduces your code.